# Console App using eclipse and mingw (not launching app in cms.exe)

Tags: c, eclipse, mingw, console-application

I am putting together a Windows console app in Eclipse c/c++ Neon (Win 10) and Mingw.

When I run the program the output appears in the console window within Eclipse, but I need/want to be able to debug with the program running a a normal Windows console app (like it would in a vs studio console app).

I have tried adding `-mwindows` to the `minGW` in Command line pattern and in linker options. I tried a number of other things I found on the web.

I have spent hours searching and nothing seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Create a file named `.gdbinit` (or it can be named whatever you want, but this one is the conventional)
2) Add a line `set new-console on` to the file. Save it.
3) Open "Debug Configurations" in the Eclipse, and select your project debug configuration.
4) Go to the "Debugger" tab.
5) Point the "GDB command file" to the file you have created.
[image]
Done! now run this debug configuration.

Comment: Hmmm - still not working. When I run the debug config i Get a "gdborig,exce has stopped working" error

Comment: Got to working - I had messed around in the other settings too much, Got it all back and added your fix - Thank you :-)